# Find a limit $\lim_{x\to0}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\cos(t^3)}{t+x}dt$

Tags: integration, limits, trigonometry

> Find
>   $$\lim_{x\to0}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\cos(t^3)}{t+x}dt$$

I'm not able to integrate it  well if integration bounds are removed (I suppose a cosine integral $\text{Ci}$ would be an answer), I suppose there's a trick. How to proceed?

Comment: You may substitute $t=xu$ and invoke the dominated convergence theorem or its weaker variants.

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes, I didn't notice it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t=xs$. Then we get the integral

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \int_0^1 \frac{\cos(x^3s^3)}{s+1}\:ds = \int_0^1\frac{1}{s+1}\:ds=\log 2$$

by dominated convergence.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $t \in [0,x]$ we have $\cos(t^3) \in [\cos(x^3),1]$

Moreover $\int_0^x \frac{1}{t+x}dt = \ln(2x) - \ln(x) = \ln(2)$

By squeeze theorem, we get result:

$\ln(2) = 1 \cdot \int_0^x \frac{1}{t+x}dt \ge \int_0^x \frac{\cos(t^3)}{t+x}dt \ge \cos(x^3) \int_0^x \frac{1}{t+x}dt = \ln(2) \cos(x^3)$

Let $x \to 0^+$

Answer (score 2):

By the Mean Value Theorem for integrals, one has
$$ \int_0^x \frac{\cos(x^3)}{t+x}\:dt=\cos(\xi^3)\int_0^x\frac{1}{t+x}\;dt=\ln2\cos(\xi^3) $$
for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$.Note that if $x\to0$, then $\xi\to0$. So
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\int_0^x \frac{\cos(x^3)}{t+x}\:dt=\ln2. $$